# Change prefix of slug

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, slug

```
title = "Preview"
url = "/preview/:slug"
layout = "default"
is_hidden = 0
robot_index = "index"
robot_follow = "follow"
[blogPost]
slug = "{{ :slug }}"
categoryPage = "manga-viewer"
==
<a class="article__inner-view" href="{{'/viewer/'|slug}}">Link to viewer page</a>
```

I need to change prefix of link from preview to viewer and I cant understand how it work.
Anybody can explain how I can change prefix?

Comment: can you share what to you trying to achieve with some example, so we can understand it better and help you in right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding you well but let me try to explain it bit may be it can help you.

> `url = "/preview/:slug"`

this is your url and slug, when you make link to this page this value will be used to make `URL`.

> `:slug` -> this is named parameter so according to url -> when we make real url then it will be like `http://example.com/preview/car` here we are using `slug -> car`

Now how you generate url for this page.

```html
<a class="article__inner-view" href="{{ 'preview'|page({ slug: 'car'}) }}">Link to viewer page</a>

// 'preview'|page({ slug: 'car'}) -> `http://example.com/preview/car`
//    ^
//  preview <- this is file name not a title so make sure to use file name
//  slug <- we used car for slug
```

> **Now to your question.**

if you wan to change `preview` -> `viewer` you need to make change in `url`.

> If you change your -> `url = "/viewer/:slug"`

```html
'preview'|page({ slug: 'car'}) -> will generate ->  `http://example.com/viewer/car`
```

if any doubt please comment.